# How to use pysnmp to delete a SNMP Table entry without "RowStatus" field?

Tags: python, snmp, pysnmp

I would like to know for those SNMP Table which doesn't have "RowStatus" field.
How could I remove an entry with given index?

The Table entry was added by

```
self.snmp_context.getMibInstrum().writeVars()
```

But I don't find any method which can be used for delete an entry?
Could @Ilya Etingof give some hint for that?

Br,
-Dapeng Jiao

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you read the SNMP RFCs you'll find out that adding or deleting operations are possible only if the table has the EntryStatus column defined (if it is an SMIv1 table) or with the RowStatus column defined (if it is an SMIv2 table).

**SMIv1 Tables with EntryStatus Column**

The EntryStatus column is used to manage the creation and deletion of conceptual rows in SMIv1 tables. This represents the status of a table entry. The status column can have the following.

- `valid(1)` - indicates that the row exists and is available for use.
- `createRequest(2)` - supplied by the manager wishing to create a row.
- `underCreation(3)` - indicates that the row is being created.
- `invalid(4)` - supplied by the manager wishing to invalidate the
  corresponding entry.

If a manager wishes to add a row, then the entryStatus column should be set to `createRequest(2)`. Immediately after the creation, the agent sets this object to `underCreation(3)`. The entry remains in the `underCreation(3)` state until it is configured. Then its value is set to `valid(1)`. If the status remains `underCreation(3)` for an abnormally long period, then the agent sets the status to `invalid(4)`.

**SMIv2 Tables with RowStatus Column**

In SMIv2 tables, the RowStatus column is used to manage the creation and deletion of conceptual rows. This column has six defined values as follows.

- `active(1)` - indicates that the conceptual row with all columns is
  available for use by the managed device.
- `notInService(2)` - indicates that the conceptual row exists in the agent, but is unavailable for use by the managed device.
- `notReady(3)` - indicates that the conceptual row exists in the agent, one or more required columns in the row are not instantiated.
- `createAndGo(4)` - supplied by a manager wishing to create a new instance of a conceptual row and make it available for use.
- `createAndWait(5)` - supplied by a manager wishing to create a new instance of a conceptual row but not making it available for use.
- `destroy(6)` - supplied by a manager wishing to delete all of the instances associated with an existing conceptual row.

There are some SNMP agents that do implement non-standard mechanisms of adding/deleting rows. So in this case it is implementation specific. But in general you can not do that without EntryStatus/RowStatus.

Answer (score 0):

With pysnmp, all changes to SNMP agent are being done with the `.writeVars()` call. It is designed that way to reuse the code for both agent-side and manager-initiated operations. So the details of the modification is determined by the OID-value pairs being passed to the call.

As @andrew-komiagin says, the way to delete SNMP table row is to SNMP SET (or `.writeVars`) the `RowStatus` columnar value to `destroy(6)`. If your table does not support `RowStatus` I guess the least intrusive way would be to just add it to either ASN.1 or Python MIB.